# Simple products price missing for bundle product options

Tags: magento2.3, price, bundled-product

I've migrated store from **Magento 1.9.3.9 CE** to **Magento 2.3.3 CE**

All entities migrated successfully but suddenly I checked few bundle products and found that it options which are simple products which don't have price.

Bundle option contains the simple products which have prices in the table but it doesn't come up with M2.

Whereas it's working fine if I add manually to `Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type::getSelectionItemData`
it's working fine.

Also after a selection when I moved to cart it showing price there.but not at `optionConfig` JSON.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php#L247

Printing above is returning price null.

I've checked pricing tables it has prices for simple products.

Any solution to this now it's getting irritating since it has price in the database.

Does anyone have a clue about this issue? Any help would be appreciated.